# How to make Objective-C Class optional based on Framework loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a class file in a framework 'X', The class file uses methods of framework 'Y'. Is there any way to make class file optional when framework 'Y' is not present during run time, Such that it shouldn't throw any compilation errors in a xcode project during compilation of project with framework 'X' and without framework 'Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't statically load framework Y's class objects by directly passing messages to them.

Let's say framework Y has the class `YYYClass`. When you reference `YYYClass` within framework X, you would normally do the following.

```
YYYClass *instance = [[YYYClass alloc] init];
```

The call to `[YYYClass alloc]` is passing a message to `YYYClass`. Now the linker requires `YYYClass` to be available.

However do something a little different.

```
YYYClass *instance = [[NSClassFromString(@"YYYClass") alloc] init];
```

Now, framework Y's class object is being dynamically loaded so the linker doesn't require the class to be available.

If framework Y is not in the final binary, then `NSClassFromString(@"YYYClass")` returns `Nil` (the class version of `nil`). `[Nil alloc]` returns `nil` and `[nil init]` returns `nil`.

The end effect is all instances of framework Y's classes will be `nil`. You need to expect this behavior and handle it.